# PayPal Cordova Plugin doesn't work with email address

Tags: java, android, cordova, paypal, payment

I used [PayPal Cordova Plugin](https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-cordova-plugin-released/) in my Android app.

I'm able to record the payment on PayPal by client-id, but don't by email address.

Where to put the email address of the merchant?

This is a piece of source from index.js:

```
    initPaymentUI: function() {
var clientIDs = {
  "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": "YOUR_PRODUCTION_CLIENT_ID",
  //"PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": "YOUR_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID"      
  "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": "emailmerchant@example.com"  

};
PayPalMobile.init(clientIDs, app.onPayPalMobileInit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of specifying the merchant email address, as the merchant is defined as being the entity with the API credentials (client_id).  See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/140) for a similar request from other merchants.